# Text field chopped off at the right side

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

My report chops off text at the right side of the page. I have activated Can Grow for the field and alignment as justified, but the problem persists. How can I correct this?

[image]

Comment: is it a formula field or text field?

Comment: Hi Siva - it is a Text field

Comment: Create a formula and write the text in formula and provide the same formatiing options and check

Comment: Its not working, i am passing RTF content for the text field

Comment: You can go to properties of the formula filed and change the interpretation to RTF that way you can make it work

Comment: i did that too but its cuts off

Answer (score 0):

File -> Page Setup -> (I recommend landscape generally speaking, 'Inches' also makes it easier to judge the size) -> Increase 'Horizontal'. Report is now wider.

The setting you had is for each column, but will not trump the page width.